# Angular routing children needs to go on /

Tags: javascript, angular

I dont know how to manage routing to be like this, for example:

- hostname/:username/
- hostname/:username/jobs
- hostname/:username/events

So the main problem here is that I always get **hostname/:username/general** which needs to be **hostname/:username/**

```
{
  path: ':username',
  component: ProfileComponent,
  resolve: {
    user: ProfileResolve
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'general',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
      path: 'general',
      component: GeneralComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'events',
      component: ProfileEventsComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'jobs',
      component: ProfileJobsComponent
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Share the html for `ProfileComponent`

Answer (score -1):

The issue is because of this `redirectTo` in case of empty route(`''`). Its value should have been `redirectTo: './general'` instead of `redirectTo: 'general'`

Change your Route Config Like this:

```
{
    path: ':username',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: './general', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'general', component: GeneralComponent },
      { path: 'events', component: ProfileEventsComponent },
      { path: 'jobs', component: ProfileJobsComponent },
    ]
}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-profile-management-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for your ref.

Comment: @krešimir-galić, could you please check if this fixed your issue? If yes, please consider marking it as an answer to help others point in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

> First of all remove remove `redirectTo` which is redirecting the blank value to `general`. You can map the default component instead.

```
path: ':username',
component: ProfileComponent,
resolve: {
  user: ProfileResolve
},
children: [
  { path: '', component: GeneralComponent },
  { path: 'general', component: GeneralComponent },
  { path: 'events', component: ProfileEventsComponent },
  { path: 'jobs', component: ProfileJobsComponent },
]
```

You can remove `redirectTo` entirely if don't want load any component `GeneralComponent`, `ProfileEventsComponent` or `ProfileJobsComponent` by default.

Comment: Why would the same component appear twice in a routing file? This doesn't too much sense.

Comment: This depends on the use case, specially when developers doesn't want to break the existing routing while making new changes.